# Changing shards of kinesis

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I couldn't find anywhere talking about what happens if reduce no.of shards i.e If I change no.of shards from 2 to 1 through the console is the consumers get link to new shard automatically or need to do something.

Answer (score 0):

If the consumer calls the `getShards()` and `getShardId()` methods, it works fine, it get the new shard information automatically.